# Creating a rule for nodes with a title beginning

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to create a rule in Drupal that will only be applied to nodes beginning with a specific phrase. I've created the rule, but am having problems with this specific condition.

I've set it to be a `Data comparison` condition, comparing the data in `node:title`. However it's the next part that I'm unsure of. I've set the operator to `equals`, and the Data Value to be `The Phrase Here*` but this hasn't worked.

Am I going about this in the completely wrong way or am I making a silly mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **"Text Comparison"** actually and set the comparison operator to **"Starts with"**. Notice that the text here is case sensitive. If you need a regular expression use this option respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with those in built triggers and actions, you may not achieve it. Instead build a custom module and write your own trigger and actions for the same!

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why I may not achieve it with this? Building a custom module is not an option for this site.

Comment: I see. Since the built in rules have limitations and are more generalized, I believe, they may not address your requirements